# How to create sitemap for static and dynamic pages

Tags: codeigniter, sitemap, codeigniter-3

I have created website using the CI framework 3.0 and still i am stuck in creating the xml sitemap for static  and dynamic pages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is very little information in your question. I suggest you [edit] it to show us your code and/or configuration. Help us help you: try to give us the information that we need to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very clear. i'm using codeigniter with the sitemap php Library. Its awesome and has clear directions: https://github.com/evert/sitemap-php

To get you started - Put the SitemapPHP folder in application/libraries

Then, in your controller, in your method you call the library like:

```
  public function makeSitemap()
{

        // APPPATH will automatically figure out the correct path
        include APPPATH.'libraries/SitemapPHP/Sitemap.php';

        // your website url
        $sitemap = new Sitemap('http://yourwebsite.com');

        // This will also need to be set by you. 
        // the full server path to the sitemap folder 
        $sitemap->setPath('/home/username/public_html/sitemap/');

        // the name of the file that is being written to
        $sitemap->setFilename('mysitemap');

        // etc etc etc 

}
```

Comment: I received the following error "Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php" although I've autoloaded sessions and by var_dump() I've check data is printing just fine. I believe this is causing the issue. $sitemap = new Sitemap('localhost/tickets/');